# addEventListener onmouseout changing function parameters not working

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, onmouseout

Hello everyone I have declared a function in javascript...

```js
    function CellOut(e, b, c){
       document.getElementById(e).style.backgroundColor = b;    
       document.getElementById(e).style.color= c; 
    }
```

And a div element...

```html
    <div id="celdiahora" onmouseout="CellOut('celdiahora', '#f88', '#fff')">Some text</div>
```

Later i need to change only the parameters of the function `CellOut` into the onmouseout event calling the next function...

```js
    function ChangeBackgroundAndColor(e, newb, newc){
       document.getElementById(e).addEventListener("mouseout", function(){
          CellOut(e, newb, newc)}, false);
    }
```

Example, if I call `ChangeBackgroundAndColor('celdiahora', '#8f8','#fff')` it must change the second parameter when the onmouseout event call the function `CellOut`. But this code do not change the color parameters when onmouseout event of the div occurs.

Some idea ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have find one solution that i think is not  the best, but it works:

I have create diferent functions with the diferents parameters:

```
function CellOutRed(e){
   document.getElementById(e).style.backgroundColor = red;    
}
function CellOutBlue(e){
   document.getElementById(e).style.backgroundColor = blue;    
}
```

And i change the onmouseout event...

```
function ChangeBackgroundRed(e){
   document.getElementById(e).addEventListener("mouseout", function(){
      CellOutRed(e)}, false);
}
function ChangeBackgroundBlue(e){
   document.getElementById(e).addEventListener("mouseout", function(){
      CellOutBlue(e)}, false);
}
```

It works...